# How to add individual row number columns for different groups in data?

Tags: r, dplyr

### Data

I am using the palmer penguins data for this reproducible example. For a simple example, I am keeping the data for the year 2007 and the species `Adelie`:

```
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)

ad <- penguins %>% 
  filter(species == "Adelie",
         year == 2007) %>% 
  select(species, island)
```

### Goal and what I tried

I want to create individual columns for row numbers for each `island` in the data. There are 3 islands:

```
> unique(ad$island)
[1] Torgersen Biscoe    Dream    
Levels: Biscoe Dream Torgersen
```

So, there should be 3 row id columns.

I have done following that works:

```
ad %>% 
  add_count(island, name = "island_counts") %>% 
  group_by(island) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = 0:(unique(island_counts)-1),
         row_id_Torgersen =  if_else(island == "Torgersen", row_id, NA_integer_),
         row_id_Biscoe =  if_else(island == "Biscoe", row_id, NA_integer_),
         row_id_Dream =  if_else(island == "Dream" , row_id, NA_integer_)
    
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()  

# A tibble: 50 x 7
   species island    island_counts row_id row_id_Torgersen row_id_Biscoe row_id_Dream
   <fct>   <fct>             <int>  <int>            <int>         <int>        <int>
 1 Adelie  Torgersen            20      0                0            NA           NA
 2 Adelie  Torgersen            20      1                1            NA           NA
 3 Adelie  Torgersen            20      2                2            NA           NA
 4 Adelie  Torgersen            20      3                3            NA           NA
 5 Adelie  Torgersen            20      4                4            NA           NA
 6 Adelie  Torgersen            20      5                5            NA           NA
 7 Adelie  Torgersen            20      6                6            NA           NA
 8 Adelie  Torgersen            20      7                7            NA           NA
 9 Adelie  Torgersen            20      8                8            NA           NA
10 Adelie  Torgersen            20      9                9            NA           NA
# ... with 40 more rows
```

But I want to do this programmatically, so that the number of new columns are not hard coded, but generated based on the number of `islands`. Is there a better solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can duplicate the island variable and then reshape to wide using `pivot_wider()`. In this way you can avoid creating individual conditionals:

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)

ad <- penguins %>% 
  filter(species == "Adelie",
         year == 2007) %>% 
  select(species, island)
#Code
ad %>% 
  add_count(island, name = "island_counts") %>% 
  group_by(island) %>% 
  mutate(row_id = 0:(unique(island_counts)-1),name=paste0('row_id_',island),
         id=row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=row_id)%>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 50 x 6
   species island    island_counts row_id_Torgersen row_id_Biscoe row_id_Dream
   <fct>   <fct>             <int>            <int>         <int>        <int>
 1 Adelie  Torgersen            20                0            NA           NA
 2 Adelie  Torgersen            20                1            NA           NA
 3 Adelie  Torgersen            20                2            NA           NA
 4 Adelie  Torgersen            20                3            NA           NA
 5 Adelie  Torgersen            20                4            NA           NA
 6 Adelie  Torgersen            20                5            NA           NA
 7 Adelie  Torgersen            20                6            NA           NA
 8 Adelie  Torgersen            20                7            NA           NA
 9 Adelie  Torgersen            20                8            NA           NA
10 Adelie  Torgersen            20                9            NA           NA
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! I am confused about the `id` column though. It is not used in `pivot_wider`, but without it, list cols are returned.

Comment: @umairdurrani Hi dear, without that var, that identifies in an unique way each row, the reshaping could not work. That is why I added it. Hope that helped :)

Comment: Got it. Thank you.